# Installing Domjudge in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, permissions, software-installation, webserver

I tried to install [Domjudge](http://domjudge.sourceforge.net/) in Fedora 19 (based on its [documentation](http://domjudge.sourceforge.net/)) and it installed successfully but when I try to start it in browser (localhost/domjudge) I get the following error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /domjudge/ on this server.

I thought maybe the problem is caused by SELinux but I disabled that and the problem still exists.

Comment: Have you enabled php in apache, and it works? What's the `.htaccess` in the `/domjudge/`? You may have to try `Allow ::1,127.0.0.1` instead of `Allow localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the permissions on the `www` directory where you installed DOMjudge, i.e. does your webserver user have read access to that directory?

If the problem still persists, then I suggest you to subscribe to our [DOMjudge-devel mailinglist](https://www.a-eskwadraat.nl/mailman/listinfo/domjudge-devel) and post there with as much details about your setup as possible: which version of DOMjudge, installation path and other configuration settings you used/changed from default, user you're installing as, etc.